# I want to write a function which prints a sum

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started learning Python a few weeks ago and I want to write a function which opens a file, counts and adds up the characters in each line and prints that those equal the total number of characters in the file.

For example, given a file test1.txt:

```
lineLengths('test1.txt')
```

The output should be:
15+20+23+24+0=82 (+0 optional)

This is what I have so far:

```
def lineLengths(filename):
     f=open(filename)
     lines=f.readlines()
     f.close()

     answer=[]
     for aline in lines:
         count=len(aline)
```

It does what I want it to do, but I don't know how to include all the of numbers added together when I have the function print.

Comment: You aren't doing anything with that `answer` list. Try writing your algorithm on paper, then simply translate to python

Comment: Also, take into account that *line separators* also count as a character..

Comment: So, you basically want the file size (minus number of linefeeds)? `os.stat(file).nt_size - open(file).read().count('\n')`

Comment: to avoid `\n` please use `f.read().splitlines()` while reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to print the sum of the length of each line, you can do it like so:

```
def lineLengths(filename):
     with open(filename) as f:
         answer = []
         for aline in f:
             answer.append(len(aline))

     print("%s = %s" %("+".join(str(c) for c in answer), sum(answer))
```

If you however also need to track lengths of all the individual lines, you can append the length for each line in your answer list by using the `append` method and then print the sum by using `sum(answer)`

Comment: @cricket_007 I agree. Updated the answer.

Comment: Yes, I am asked to print all of the lengths of the individual lines added together as well- my question is how to format this part within the print command

Comment: @MathStudent1324 Edited the answer for print formatting you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
f=open(filename)
mylist = f.read().splitlines()
sum([len(i) for i in mylist])
```

Answer (score 0):

This should have the output you want : x+y+z=a

```
def lineLengths(filename):
   count=[]
   with open(filename) as f: #this is an easier way to open/close a file
     for line in f:
       count.append(len(line))
   print('+'.join(str(x) for x in count) + "=" + str(sum(count))
```

Comment: I like this approach but I am told join is invalid syntax when I try to run it

Comment: @MathStudent1324 I forgot a `.` between `'+'` and `join`

Answer (score 0):

Simple as this:

```py
sum(map(len, open(filename)))
```

`open(filename)` returns an iterator that passes through each line, each of which is run through the `len` function, and the results are `sum`med.

Answer (score 0):

Separate you problem in function : a responsible by return total sum of lines and other to format sum of each line.

```
def read_file(file):
    with open(file) as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
    return lines

def format_line_sum(lines):
    lines_in_str = []

    for line in lines:
        lines_in_str.append(str(line)

    return "+".join(str_lines))

def lines_length(file):
    lines = read_file(file)

    total_sum = 0
    for line in lines:
        total_sum += len(line)

    return format_lines_sum(lines) + "=" + total_sum
```

And to use:

```
print(lines_length('file1.txt'))
```

Comment: I am supposed to print instead of return- will this still work?

Comment: Also is there a way to include the formatting when I print the function instead of defining a separate function (format_line_sum)? I haven't learned what map is yet and we haven't done anything with nested functions.

Comment: Ok , I will to refactor to use procedural way.

Comment: Refactored , I separated in functions to don't mix the logics of the each processing.

Ex: The return in function is useful , because you processing data and formatting a way to return them , after just print in your "app".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your output is literal, something like this should work.

You can use python `sum()` function when you figure out how to add numbers to the list

```
def lineLengths(filename):
     with open(filename) as f:
         line_lengths = [len(l.rstrip()) for l in f]
         summ = '+'.join(map(str, line_lengths))  # can only join strings 
     return sum(line_lengths), summ 

total_chars, summ = lineLengths(filename)
print("{} = {}".format(summ, total_chars))
```

Comment: It is not "a map", it is simply the function `map()`

Answer (score 0):

Once you read lines from file you can count sum using:

```
sum([len(aline) for aline in lines])
```